# Getting Cookie Error jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler: Not storing invalid cookie:

Tags: jmeter

I am getting cookies error mentioned below:

`WARN  jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler: Not storing invalid cookie:  for URL https://xatt90.xdev.motive.com/ssc/auth/1.0/validate?soaTraceId=5a1829d6-0aac-4aa2-d37b-a433d6c3208a (Illegal domain attribute ".att.com". Domain of origin: "xatt90.xdev.motive.com")`

How can we handle this by using cookie manager in jmeter?

I have tried to add a cookie manager but it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the jmeter.properties file you need to set the following:

```
#CookieManager.check.cookies=true
```

to:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

Be sure to remove the leading # in order to un-comment the line.